# Hbase Schema design for facebook data

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to get the posts from my facebook page and put them into hbase. If I design a relational data model I have three tables with one to many mapping like this:

> Post has multiple comments and comment has multiple reply comments.

After doing research I came up with this schema:

> PostId would be the row key. Then one column family "data" containing post, comment, reply as column qualifier with their objects as values.

Is this the right schema? Please suggest how can it be done if I am missing something as I am new to Hbase and Hadoop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one of the biggest considerations with designing a schema for hbase (or any nosql db) is how it will be queried.  can you add some details around that to your question?

Comment: @MartinSerrano I have the same requirement. I would like to get any data(be it posts, comments, or replies) with a keyword search. eg. I want to get all data having "Nasa" keyword in it. How can I achieve this?